# How to run a double loop using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have the following MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

N <- 199
K <- N+1
x <- rep(0,N)
x[1] <- 0.5
time <- c(1:K)

G <- c(2.7, 2.9, 3.0, 3.5, 3.82, 3.83, 3.84, 3.85)
g <- 2.7

for (t in 1:N) {
  x[t+1] = g*x[t]*(1-x[t])
}
plot(time,x)
```

In this code, `G` is unused and is a vector of values for `g`. Currently I have a plot for the first value of `g=2.7`. What I want to do is to loop through values of `G` and create separate plots for each. I have the following code that I am trying to do this with:

```
for (g in G) {
  x_g <- N+1
  x_g[1] <- 0.5
  for (t in 1:N) {
    x_g[t+1] = g*x_g[t]*(1-x_g[t])
    plot(time,x_g)
}
}
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I am trying to create separate `x_g` variables as I cannot figure out how to 'wipe' the values of `x` from the original code. I think I am:

1. Using the `for(g in G)` loop incorrectly
2. Taking the wrong approach by using separate `x_g` variables

Any tips on how to approach this/do this properly? I am unfamiliar with the use of matrices in R, is that the surefire way of approaching these types of problems?

Comment: Move the `plot(time,x_g)` statement from the inside the inner loop to outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to keep your code style, I guess your nested `for` loop might be something like below

```
for (g in G) {
  x_g <- rep(0,N+1)
  x_g[1] <- 0.5
  for (t in 1:N) {
    x_g[t+1] = g*x_g[t]*(1-x_g[t])
  }
  plot(time,x_g)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @ThomasIsCoding but it does not create the variables `x_g`:

```
library(ggplot2)

N <- 199
K <- N+1
x <- rep(0,N)
x[1] <- 0.5
time <- c(1:K)

G <- c(2.7, 2.9, 3.0, 3.5, 3.82, 3.83, 3.84, 3.85)
g <- 2.7

for (g in G) {
  for (t in 1:N) {
    x[t+1] = g*x[t]*(1-x[t])
  }
  plot(time,x, main = g)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I accepted @ThomasIsCoding answer as he was first, but this is the version I will be using!